# Two not x.startswith() in if statement

Tags: python, if-statement

Let's suppose I have this list

```
y = ['bat','bats','cat','cats','dog','dogs']
```

I want to remove everything that starts with bat or cat.  Therefore, only 'dog' and 'dogs' should be left in the list.

For some reason, if I type this:

```
for i in y:
     if not i.startswith('bat') or not i.startswith('cat'):
          print(i)
```

Each item will be printed.

But, if I just have one of the clauses:

```
for i in y:
     if not i.startswith('bat'):
          print(i)
```

'bat' and 'bats' are not printed as expected.

What is going on with the second not i.startswith() expression?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: A word can't both start with bat and cat. Your logic is wrong. You need an `and` not an `or`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic is wrong on this line:

```
if not i.startswith('bat') or not i.startswith('cat'):
```

With the statement being an OR, only one of the conditions has to be true (or in this case, not true for a NOT statement) to enter the if.

However if it is changed to an AND statement, both statements have to be true to enter the if condition.

```
if not i.startswith('bat') and not i.startswith('cat'):
```

Comment: Ah, I see that makes a lot more sense.